# SQL oracle check available date

Tags: sql, oracle

I need query to check not conflict date (eg. Request for holidays).

Select all from table 1 where input parameter is date_from and date_to from new draft row.

Table 1 (Request of my work colleagues) :

```
Select '1' as id, to_date('07.05.2021') as date_from,to_date('14.05.2021') as date_to, '-' as yes_no from dual
union
Select '2' as id, to_date('11.05.2021') as date_from,to_date('18.05.2021') as date_to, 'No' as yes_no from dual
union
Select '3' as id, to_date('10.05.2021') as date_from,to_date('15.05.2021') as date_to, '-' as yes_no from dual
union
Select '4' as id, to_date('01.05.2021') as date_from,to_date('04.05.2021') as date_to, 'No' as yes_no from dual
```

New draft row (My request):

```
Select to_date('05.05.2021') as date_from,to_date('10.05.2021') as date_to, 'New' as yes_no from dual
```

How get all row from table 1 where new row don't have a conflict.
In my example (row id 1 and 3).

Comment: As an aside, you really should supply a format mask with your use of to_date.  Like this:    to_date('14.05.2021','dd.mm.yyyy')    Without the format mask, you are depending on the client's setting of NLS_DATE_FORMAT, which may or may no be what you expect.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't have a conflict"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to check overlapping periods to be sure there is no overlap:

```
select t2.*, t1.*
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.date_to < t23.date_from or
        t1.date_from > t2.date_to;
```

That is, there is no overlap if the second table ends before a row starts or starts after a row ends.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9e4128db2dc412cc624c9dca61a7a79c) is a db<>fiddle.  This returns rows 2 and 4, because those rows have no overlaps.

Comment: Tnx for help but I get 3 rows.

Comment: @Pointer . . . I fixed a typo and added a db<>fiddle.